# jQuery find elements then make into comma separated list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have numerous text boxes on my page, and I want to add the values from them to another element when a button is clicked. However, my current code outputs the values like this:

```
Value oneValue twoValue three
```

I would much prefer for them to come out like this instead:

```
Value one, Value two, Value three
```

my current JS is like this:

```
var textInput = $(".random-input").text();

$(".output-box").append(textInput);
```

Comment: @u_mulder I did what's the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because the elements are all being interpreted together. To fix that you can `map()` the text values to an array and `join()` it:

```
var textInput = $(".random-input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(', ');    
$(".output-box").text(textInput);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/fcnLnLkj/)

The above is assuming `.output-box` is a standard element. If it's another textbox, you'd need to use `val(textInput)`.

---

**Update: Oct 2020**

The above example can now also be made more succinct by using an ES6 arrow function, but note that this is unsupported in IE.

```
var textInput = $(".random-input").map((i, el) => el.value).get().join(', ');    
$(".output-box").text(textInput);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through each input and then using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var textInput = [];
$(".random-input").each(function() {
  textInput.push(this.value)
});

$(".output-box").append(textInput.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<input type='text' class='random-input' value='val1' />
<div class='output-box'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rory McCrossan code is moved to the jQuery function **joinVal**:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    joinVal: function (separator)
    {
        if (typeof separator === 'undefined')
            separator = ",";

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this && $this.length > 1)
            return $this.map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get().join(separator);
        else
            return $this.val();
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
var textInput = $(".random-input").joinVal();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/4j892h0u/3/